# How to change namespace by Rancher kubectl

Tags: namespaces, kubectl, rancher

I installed rancher via podman and created a namespace. Now when I start the kubectl shell via the UI, I am not able to change the namespace via:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=XXX
```

I get

> error: open /home/shell/.kube/config: read-only file system

It's also not possible to change permission for /home/shell/.kube/config. No luck with any user neither with admin.

So my question is, how can I change the namespace using the rancher kubectl shell?